# Pass data as list of dictionaries to Django Formset?

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

I have a model called `Reporter` and a straight-forward `ReporterForm` and a formset based on it called `ReporterFormset` as below:

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ReporterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reporter
        fields = '__all__'

ReporterFormset = modelformset_factory(Reporter, form=ReporterForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)
```

I want to save new data coming as list of dictionaries like:

```
data = [
    {'name': 'x'}, 
    {'name': 'y'}
]
```

So, I tried to do:

```
reporters_formset = ReporterFormset(initial=data)
```

But it shows that the formset is not valid after executing `reporters_formset.is_valid()` and with empty `reporters_formset.errors`.

How can I achieve such?